Why do you need to beat a DC of 15 to hide?
What is the purpose of the DC 15 Stealth requirement for hiding?
2024 PHB pg 368 states the following for Hide [Action]

With the Hide action, you try to conceal yourself. To do so, you must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity (Stealth) check while you’re Heavily Obscured or behind Three-Quarters Cover or Total Cover, and you must be out of any enemy’s line of sight; if you can see a creature, you can discern whether it can see you.
On a successful check, you have the Invisible condition. Make note of your check’s total, which is the DC for a creature to find you with a Wisdom (Perception) check.
The condition ends on you immediately after any of the following occurs: you make a sound louder than a whisper, an enemy finds you, you make an attack roll, or you cast a spell with a Verbal component.

There seem to be two requirements, yet it appears that they both provide the same outcome.  The DC15 Dex (Stealth) gives you the Invisible Condition, but the very next sentence mentions the Perception check required to find you.  So which one is it?
The only viable outcomes that I can think of are:

The DC15 Stealth gives you the Invisible Condition until a different creature makes a Perception Check (or has the Passive Perception?) to notice you on their turn.  Which then would rule that you have the Invisible Condition up to that instance.

The DC15 Stealth gives you the Invisible Condition AND THEN a successful Perception Check (or Passive Perception) allows another creature only to discern where you are (the hiding creature retains the Invisible Condition).


The DC15 Stealth check (to me) is an ambiguous requirement.  Specifically, the PHB does not provide any negative constraints concerning this requirement.  I have seen, on other platforms, quite a few DMs throwing out the DC15 requirement altogether.  I am considering the same,  but I wanted to ask what I am missing before modifying the rules.

I also wanted to ask the following, but I'm not sure how to ask this without it being an opinionated question:
The Hide rule states you are no longer hidden if you make an attack roll.  I would assume the same rule SHOULD apply to casting some spells, like Fireball.  I would think if you're hidden and cast Fireball (using Subtle Spell or something similar), you would reveal your position.

@TreeSpawned Yes I get that, my thought is, given the description of some of the spells, specifically Fireball, where it says, "a bright streak flashes from you to a point..." is it unrealistic to rule that that description would give your location away? Same thing with Lightning Bolt or even Magic Missile?

It sounds like this should be a diffierent question. Certainly nothing we can discuss at length here in the comments.  It is cerntainly not unrealistic to rule and spells do what they say, so it would make sense, whether or not that is RAW i cannot say with certainty.

Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, frame challenges, corrections to any misconceptions or misunderstandings the asker may have, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

re: your bonus question in comments: For dnd-2014, see Does a hidden creature that casts a spell reveal its position? - there is just a blanket rule, presumably based on spells having verbal and/or somatic components.  Also Spell attacks while hidden / Casting spells while out of hearing and sight .  As always, the DM can overrule the general rule to fit the specific case.

Because hiding is a medium difficulty ability check
A DC 15 ability Check is of medium difficulty as explained in chapter 1. Anytime you try to hide you need to beat this roll, as that's what the game designates the difficulty of hiding in general to be. In the old rules the DC was the passive perception score of the creature(s) you were hiding from. This rules simplifies that. You are hidden when you reach that number and you aren't when you don't. This means that under the 2024 rules you cannot hide from a dumb ogre with a passive perception of 8 by just beating that number, you have to roll at least a 15, otherwise your characters fails to hide.
Once you succeed on this check you are hidden, which gives you the invisible condition. However, what comes afterwards is the same in the old rules: you note down your total, which is the DC to beat for anyone to try to find you with a Perception Check, which will probably be from the new search action. If that happens the condition ends, as the quote says:

The condition ends on you immediately after any of the following occurs: [...] an enemy finds you [...]

Now how passive perception factors into this is an interesting case. The hide rules make no explicit mentions of it, they just talk about a "a Wisdom (Perception) check", so let's look at what the rules about passive perception in the rules glossary say:

The DM uses this score when determining whether a creature notices something without consciously making a Wisdom (Perception) check

It says it can be used to replace a Perception Check, like the one spotting a hidding creature, but it doesn't say that you automatically notices everything that is below your passive perception, it says that "the DM" uses it. This sounds like it's ultimately a DM's decision whether to factor passive perception into the hiding rules, or not.

If this is the rule (which I think it is) I once again despair. Passive perception now does nothing, yay.

@SeriousBri: Passive checks never actually did anything - that would suggest an active doing of a character, in my understanding. The DM can let the characters notice something if the DM wants them to do, or to be more precise: at least the DM considers them having a chance for that outcome. With passive checks the DM has a quantitative measure of the difficulty for a success in this way. If the DM uses this or not is open to the DM. I for myself use passive checks almost only for NPCs, situations with characters I resolve narratively.

@Flynxer passive perception was always the floor for the check an NPC needed to hide. You could build a character who could pretty much always spot hidden enemies, and not waste actions in combat just trying to perceive. Now your character stats are completely separated from the check, and you have to actually spend your action looking for hidden enemies. That is (in my opinion) a much less fun thing to do, as all you really get to do then is inform the rest of the group, but you don't get to actually do anything about it yourself. This makes for less fun play.

@SeriousBri Maybe, you'd need to see it in play. A very effective mechanism to find a hidden creature, regardless of the character's perception score, is to move to a position where there is no cover or obscurement between you and where the hidden creature is logically likely to be. Hiding doesn't erase a creature's memory of what just happened. I think I see this kind of gameplay, plus smart use of area effect spell etc, happening a lot more often in practice than "my stat means I ignore the effect".

@SeriousBri The DM can still decide that PCs with passive perception >15 immediately notice (with no action) NPCs who are hiding, just as they can decide that NPCs with high passive perception spot hiding PCs

@Caleth It would not be PCs with 15+ Perception, it would be those that have a higher Passive Perception, than the total that the hider rolled.

@Caleth the DM can decide a lot of things, but the rule doesn't call it out. Why is doesn't mention it is beyond me.

@SeriousBri it's in the glossary, not the text of hiding, sure, but it's still the rule

@TreeSpawned my point was that below 15 passive perception, there's nothing to passively notice, because of the change to hiding

The wording "The DM uses this score" could be because they are the only one in a position to, because the NPC half of the comparison is (potentially) hidden from the players

as a GM I would use passive persuasion as a guide.  With a high enough passive persuasion, you would still remain "hidden" but the entity might have a sense that somethings amiss, although they can't see it.  Then its up to perception checks and hope that the bacon being cooked in the next room (Prestidigitation anyone?) enough to distract said entity from the smell of sweat running down the hiders face.


Why do you need to beat a DC of 15 to hide?

Because the rules say so

What is the purpose of the DC 15 Stealth requirement for hiding?

That's pretty hard to answer without comments from the designers.

So which one is it?

Both
In the 2024 rules, there are two fundamental requirements to hide.

you must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity (Stealth) check


The condition ends [... if] an enemy finds you

Thus, by the rules, you must succeed on the initial, uncontested, static DC to hide. This grants you the invisible condition (at least possibly). Further, if you make noise, an attack roll, or any enemy's passive Perception, or active action to Search succeeds, the [invisible] condition ends.
Further, carried over from the 2014 rules is this text.

If you are hidden when you make an attack roll, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

In the 2014 playtest, "D&D Playtest: How to Play," this read

If you make a noise, such as yelling a warning to an ally or knocking over a vase, you give away your position and are thus no longer hidden.

Note: the playtest didn't call out making an attack specifically (though, arguably making an attack is making a noise), but had the extremely helpful "and are thus no longer hidden". This didn't make it into the official rules text, but was the assumption, at least according to podcasts...
This point of confusion was carried forward into the 2024 rules with

If you are hidden when you make an attack roll, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

Disregard the primary check?

I have seen, on other platforms, quite a few DMs throwing out the DC15 requirement altogether. I am considering the same, but I wanted to ask what I am missing before modifying the rules.

The primary DC 15 Dexterity (Stealth) check is a completely dissociative mechanic
which I raised concerns about during the playtest.

A dissociated mechanic is one which is disconnected from the game world

Begin rant
Fundamentally, the static DC of 15 and the requirement to be out of any visible enemy’s line of sight add unnecessary restrictions that limit the utility of hiding.
For instance, consider an enemy with a passive Perception of 8 who is in light obscurity—like a creature relying on darkvision without a light source. This enemy effectively has a passive Perception of 3. However, to hide from them, you must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity (Stealth) check. This dissociative mechanic disregards the actual conditions affecting visibility, effectively flooring all passive Perception checks at 15 when, in this case, it should have been 3.
Additionally, the requirement to be out of any visible enemy’s line of sight creates further complications. If you’re heavily obscured or behind total cover, it might be impossible to meet this criterion. Moreover, this rule implies that if one enemy can see you, you cannot hide from any of them, regardless of their actual ability to perceive you. This assumption resembles a hive mind, which should not exist without special abilities.
While it's true that an enemy who can see you may alert others, this mechanic removes tactical options, such as the ability to feign that you are unaware. The notion that you can discern whether a creature can see you feels unnecessary and undermines the strategy of stealth.
The introduction of the "Hidden" condition also reflects a misunderstanding of the mechanics of hiding. Hiding should not be a binary state; rather, it should depend on each enemy's perception of you. The rules should allow attempts to hide, even if those attempts are less than effective.
Before the introduction of the static DC, players could succeed with lower rolls, particularly due to the -5 penalty on passive Perception in light obscurity.
In the playtest, the condition "hidden" was introduced, which made little sense as hiding should depend on the perceptions of specific enemies. While the term "hidden" has been replaced with "invisible" in the published 2024 rules, this still complicates the distinction between being undetectable and simply unseen.
Overall, these mechanics have evolved in ways that can diminish the strategic depth of hiding, making it less intuitive and less rewarding for players who want to engage with stealth effectively.
TLDR, hidden should be better than invisible
Being hidden means your enemy is not aware of you while invisible means your enemy is aware, knows your location, but you are not visible to them. This primarily impacts surprise, which was also significantly nerfed in 2024.
This is nothing new
In the 2014 playtest, there were conditions for hiding, including 1/2 cover, which any creature could provide. This created complications, particularly for lightfoot halflings, whose ability to hide behind larger creatures became less advantageous than the general rule. However, the final 2014 rules omitted specific conditions for stealth entirely. Instead of defined mechanics, DMs must parse existing stipulations presented in plain language, along with features that imply nonexistent rules. This omission means determining conditions is (or was with 2014) subject to DM interpretation, leading to inconsistencies between different tables. What might work for one DM could be entirely different at another’s table.
How I adjudicate this (2014 or 2024)

Disregard the primary check, it adds barriers and complexity without benefit.
Ask for a Dexterity (Stealth) check only when it matters*. When a character chooses to hide, I do not ask for a check. They are simply choosing the behavior. If you ask for the check up front, the player will have information their character should not have. When hiding from an enemy, on that enemy's turn is when I ask for the character's Dexterity (Stealth) check and I compare it to the enemy's passive Perception, or active if they are "searching". Provided the character is successful, this may continue to occur multiple times on successive turns for that same enemy.
If an enemy succeeds on their contested Perception/ Stealth check, the character is no longer hiding - from that enemy. This has no impact on other enemies.
If the player makes a noise, attacks or otherwise compromises their ability to hide, the player is no longer hidden (from anyone) and no further Perception checks are required.

* This is very similar to how Keith Ammann adjudicates in his excellent treatise "Live to Tell the Tale" 

Re: the statement This dissociative mechanic disregards the actual conditions affecting visibility.  I believe the argument for the change is that being hidden is about a lot more than just being visible.  You could be trying to hide in complete darkness, but if you bang your armor or weapon against something, kick up some dust and sneeze, kick some rocks, drop your coin purse, or let out a wet fart when you squat down, your enemies will still have a good idea where you are. Arguably, there should be an auditory equivalent to concealment, but that can be played as Advantage when applicable.

@RisingZan
This is why Perception is intended to encompass all sensory input. It also raises the issue of multiple DCs for a creature with Keen Senses. A creature may smell you (and thus know your location), but may not see you.

Yes, but it's also why there's a flat 15 for the "Did you hide without making noise or otherwise reveal your position" check.  Those other sensory inputs get handled by the passive and active perception checks which come after the initial hiding.  If you fail to hit that 15 DC, it just means you didn't hide very well and anyone of average perception can still detect you.

@RisingZan Where is this explanation? If it exists, I'll add that, but postulation is not rules.

@RisingZan the average person in DND (a commoner) has a perception bonus on 0 and passive perception of 10. They can only meet a DC15 perception check 25% of the time. The average person is not good at spotting hiding creatures. Now in real life hiding is hard, but DND has rules and maths which the hiding rules seemingly ignore. What happens when the hider rolls a 14? They fail to hide but the commoner still can't passively spot them? Schroedinger's hidden state?

One of my players unintentionally made an argument in favor of the DC 15 initial requirement (we are currently doing hybrid rules). He argued that when you try and be stealthy to some degree you know how well you did absent of external perception. You can hear yourself stepping on creaky floors or dry leaves/twigs. I had to concede it was a good point I am still on the fence about some of the new stealth rules as well but thought I would throw that in.

It makes hiding a simple binary state, rather than a more complex relation to every other creature.
Your interpretation 1 is close to correct, but it ignores the other ways that hiding can end, and it's making timing assumptions that I don't think hold.
Being Invisible doesn't mean you are transparent, it means that none of your enemies can currently see you.

Because the designers wanted hiding to be [...] simple - This seems highly likely, but do you have a source for this?

Big [citation needed] here. Anytime we say “because the designers…” we really need to see the designers telling us that, otherwise you’re just guessing, and we try to avoid guessing here.

@ThomasMarkov removed the implication of designer intent

It makes hiding a simple binary state, rather than a more complex relation to every other creature. very succinct and accurate, by my estimation! I still question the why :-)

@Wyrmwood because WoTC want a game that is appealing to the most amount of people, and complexity for little benefit isn't massively appealing
